# Shamir secret sharing, recovery of keys which have 0 bytes in front of them?

Tags: secret-sharing, private-set-intersection

From what I know SSS creates a polynomial with `a0` = secret key and interpolates it on recovery using `k` coeffs. if a0 is a number, can SSS fully recover keys with 0 bytes in front of them?

Example, If I make shards for `00d3e4bb740636a65d31a8b00793187c` will I get `d3e4bb740636a65d31a8b00793187c` upon reconstruction or `00d3e4bb740636a65d31a8b00793187c`??

Comment: I thinks this is clearly implementation specific and you are mentioning nothing about your implementation.

Comment: @JAAAY Okay, let me reframe, is it possible to implement SSS in such a way that it can reconstruct the whole key which has 0s appended in front of them?

Comment: JAAAY is right. Probably you have a print issue. I'm voting to close...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about programming error..

Comment: If you are working with numerical values then commonly they are encoded as unsigned numbers. The `00` byte would be required for big endian, **signed** integers as the next byte is `d3` and thus has the highest sign bit set in the usual two-complement notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shamir-secret sharing works over a field (typically either modulo a prime or in an extension field). The secret you share (and reconstruct) is an element in this field so either a number between 0 and p-1 (if you work modulo prime) or in general an element of the field. It is up to you to encode your secret into the field and then parse it back during reconstruction.